# should i be worried with this warning message?

Tags: r, warnings, r-caret

I at moment trying to train my dataset, seem to get an warning message as output..

the function on the other hand generates an output, but is the output wrong?

`G2M1` can be loaded from here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/flmex4vuawql3zu/data-labeled-2-1-dpi100-sigma0.6.RData?dl=0

```
train_control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10)
fit <- train(x = signif(G2M1$data,digits = 2), y = G2M1$labels , method = "nb", trControl=train_control)
```

the warning message I get is:

```
In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
```

what does it mean and should i be worried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you resample from a validation set, there may or may not be a complete complement of all the factor levels in a predictor variable, and so prediction on the basis of missing values may not be possible. Whether that is true depends on the type of model.  If this is only a warning, then you need to evaluate whether you got sufficient runs in the cross-vaidation runs to be meaningful. You may be able to see useful results.

If it's an error, then you would see "ERROR" in the message and execution would have halted.

Comment: > "If this is only a warning, then you need to evaluate whether you got sufficient runs in the cross-vaidation runs to be meaningful. You may be able to see useful results." 

it is a warning, how  would you want me to evaluate that?

Comment: Well. I'd start by  looking at `length(fit)`, `names(fit)` and `str(fit)` to see what made it through. If you only lost one or two cross-validations, then you could still have useful material to evaluate and might then considering running again with higher `number`.